# How can I tablesort by term weight instead of term name?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

I've got a View for Nodes and display some fields as column.
All columns should be sortable.

One field is a term reference. In order to sort the terms by names I create a relationship on the reference field and add a field Term Name with reference to this relationship.
As a result I get the name and I can alphabatically sort the names.

But even more I would like to sort on the term weight instead.
Is there any solution out there?